# SVN Losing history when importing trunk

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I was working in a branch of a project and made many changes to that branch on my local machine. I did not commit those changes to the repository.

Then, by mistake, I erased the .SVN folder in my project. Did I loose traces of all the changes I've made?

I can reimport that branch in SVN, but I will loose all of the history for that branch. Eventually, that branch will become the trunk. If I do so, the trunk will inly include the history since the branch was reimported.

Any way around my problem? Don't tell me "switch to GIT". This not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes to uncommitted files are calculated on-the-fly thanks to the original files stored at `.svn`.

I suggest you merely check out a new working copy somewhere else and replace your files. With *replace* I mean:

1. Delete all your code (i.e., all the files except the `.svn` folder) from the new working copy.
2. Move all your files from the damaged working copy into the new one.

With *delete* and *move* I'm referring to good old file system operations, not Subversion commands or anything else. Since you use Windows you can drag files with the mouse in Windows explorer.

Comment: The problem is I don't know exactly which files I've edited. There are so many of them...

Comment: Remove everything except the `.svn` folder and copy **all your source code**.

Comment: Will it create a change on files I haven't modified ? I'll give it a try!

Comment: It works. The only problem I found with the solution is when you have deleted files. Deleted files will remain in the destination folder.

Comment: @pmartin8 I apparently didn't' explain myself properly. Please check my edited answer.